# how to get POJO object in javascript from a JSON?

Tags: javascript, java, json, node.js

I have a JSON :

> { "a" : "123",
>   "b" : "rrdf",
>   "c" : {
>         "french" : "frnch",
>         "german" : "gmn",
>         "spanish" : "spns",
>         "italian" : "itln"
>   }
>   }

I want to extract the value of c(which is very complex) as this:::

```
{french=frnch,
  german=gmn",
  spanish=spns",
  italian=itln"}
```

Comment: `var obj = { "a" : "123", "b" : "rrdf", "c" : { "french" : "frnch", "german" : "gmn", "spanish" : "spns", "italian" : "itln" } }; console.log(obj.c);`

Comment: A POJO stands for: `Plain Old Java Object`. It has nothing to do with JavaScript

Comment: you guys can see = there.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the JSON to an object and use `objectName.propertyName` e.g. `obj.c`

```js
var obj = {
  "a": "123",
  "b": "rrdf",
  "c": {
    "french": "frnch",
    "german": "gmn",
    "spanish": "spns",
    "italian": "itln"
  }
}

console.log(obj.c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var a = {
  "a": "123",
  "b": "rrdf",
  "c": {
    "french": "frnch",
    "german": "gmn",
    "spanish": "spns",
    "italian": "itln"
  }
}
console.log(a.c)
```